# PHP session ID not sticking in Safari

Tags: php, safari, session

What reasons could there be for PHP to provide a new session ID to a Safari browser at absolutely random intervals?

Could the PHPSESSID cookie be expiring in the client?
Or maybe something else, more complex?

Comment: I bet it has something to do with cookies!

Comment: The cookie expiring / not being sent by Safari would be the most logical reason. You could enable Safari's debug mode & check requests for the cookie. Or log them in your webservers access log for easy retrieval.

Answer (score 3):

Safari has a setting to only allow cookies from the site that is being visited.  If your database or web service is on another box, it will block the cookie and therefore the session will not be saved...

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file you have the config option

```
session.use_only_cookies
```

If this is set to true, PHP will use only cookies to keep track of the session.

Otherwise PHP has a fallback method to use get, if the browser has disabled cookies.

So, if you set this option to false, Sessions will also work, if your Safari has cookies disabled.

However this has a security drawback. Some users, that copy your URL and send them to friends, might copy the SID string with the URL and therefore reveal their session to their friends. If you store the SID in cookies only, this could not happen.

Regarding how long a session lives, have a look at the **session.gc_maxlifetime** config option:

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the
>   number of seconds after which data
>   will be seen as 'garbage' and cleaned
>   up. Garbage collection occurs during
>   session start.

Answer (score -1):

add `session_set_cookie_params(0, "/");` after `session_start();`

the backslash made sessions work for me in Safari.